# AngularJS Complex Model with Incomplete/Partial Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, model

We have an application developed on AngularJS and we're trying to improve its flow and architecture. I'm not really used to AngularJS development, so I read [this article](https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/data-model-architecture-in-angular) about **Data Model Architeture** and [this one](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc#.556s7wkh1) about **Angular Model Objects with Javascript Classes**.

Basically, those articles advice developers to create a standard model (e.g. User) with can handle the user data (e.g. name, picture etc..) and use these object across the Angular application.

**My question is how can we still use these objects to handle objects with  incomplete/partial data?**

For instance:

My User Model has the following structure:

```
User
  + name
  + picture
  - sensitiveData
  + doSomethingWithSensitiveData()
```

**CASE 1**

When users access their own profile within the application, they have access to this "sensitive data". The api returns: `name, picture and sensitiveData` and hydrates the User Model.

**CASE 2**

When they view another user's profile, they can only see the name and picture. The api returns just `name, picture` and hydrates the User Model.

**CASE 3**

When they are searching for users, they can only see the users' names. The api returns just `name` and hydrates the User Model.

---

If I use the same class for both cases, the `sensitiveData` property would be empty in **CASE 2**, so the method `doSomethingWithSensitiveData()` would probably fail or throw an `Error`. **CASE 3** would fail as well.

---

So, what is the best practice to work with complex models in these cases? Is this approach conceptually correct?